# How to avoid axios encoding "&" character into ":"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

```
import axios from "axios";

const instance =  axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://testsite.com'
});

const url = '/books';

const data = {
    name: "Of Mice &amp; Men"
};

const response = instance.put(
    url, 
    data,
    ...
);
```

When using either POST or PUT, the payload will be:

```
{"name":"Of Mice : 
amp; Men"}:
```

How do I prevent this encoding of the "&" character from happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Cannot reproduce. https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-hill-szm2q9 Take a look at the network requests in devtools and you'll see a payload of `{"name":"Of Mice &amp; Men"}`, as expected. How did you measure this? At the server?

Comment: @spender confirmed it in Chrome Dev Tools and by outputting what the script is receiving on the backend. I'm genuinely confused about what might be causing it.

Comment: Is it possible that server middleware is processing this before it hits "user" code?

Comment: honestly, I don't think so. it's just axios installed via npm on a CRA, nothing else. I'll do some more digging, try to figure out what's going on.